# Let AA and BB be nn x nn matrix. Show that for any

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i)Let $A$ and $B$ be $n$ x $n$ matrix. Show that for any $n$ x $n$ matrix $X$ , 
rank$$\begin{bmatrix} A &X\\0 &B \end{bmatrix}$$ $\ge$ rank$(A)$ + rank$(B)$

ii)Let $A$ and $B$ be a complex matrices with the same colum number. If $Bx=0$ whenever $Ax=0$ ,show that rank$$\begin{bmatrix} A \\B \end{bmatrix}$$ = rank$(A)$

for number (ii) I get the fact that rank$(B)$$\leq$ rank$(A)$.But I'm stuck to get the result as we need

Comment: What’s your definition of rank?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you realise that rank is number of linear independent rows (or columns) the solution is almost obvious.

Let $M = \begin{bmatrix} A &X\\0 &B \end{bmatrix}$.

1. If $X=0$ then immediately $rank(M)=rank(A)+rank(B)$. Now let us update $X$ by adding non-zero rows one by one. However, this will not add linear dependencies between any two rows  of $M$ one with nonzero entries from $A$ and another with nonzero entries from $B$ since they are linearly independent. Thus rank of $M$ will never decrease. But it can increase, so we get inequality.
2. $B-A=0$ because $(B-A)x=0$ for any $x$, so

$$rank(\begin{bmatrix} A \\B \end{bmatrix}) =rank(\begin{bmatrix} A \\B-A \end{bmatrix}) = rank(\begin{bmatrix} A \\0 \end{bmatrix}) = rank(A).$$